# Automatic logout does not change title bar when editing

Tags: bug, edits, logout

Sometimes I start to answer a question on Stack Overflow and then get distracted for a bit/few minutes and get logged out (likely some timeout or whatever) from my "automatic login" from another source via my browser.

*If* I then try to post the answer it says I cannot - see error above...but there *isn't* any error.

I know from a few attempts that it *did* log me out because if I refresh or open another window and then log back in, it *will* let me post. It is kind of a bad user experience (bug) that the active window still shows my icon, reputation points, etc. in the upper right, but it is logged out behind the scenes here.

Comment: This is likely a setting in your browser or a browser extension, potentially for security. As far as I've experienced, the only time-based, automatic logout from Stack Exchange is after *30 days*.

Comment: I did not notice this until fairly recently and am unaware of any changes (none by me that I know of) to my browser (chrome)